# Can't compile Java Code that Counts a Recursive Linked List

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I have made two different versions of trying to compile a Java code that counts a linked list. I have changed the order of the main string, as well as variables, but I continue to get the same error: "Error: Main method not found in class Rainbow, please define the main method as:
public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application". Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I have to keep the public class Rainbow or else I get an error as well.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
    
public class Rainbow {  
    
    // Create the nodes for the linked list Rainbow
    class Node {
        String data;
        Node next;
        Node(String k)
        {
            data = k;
            next = null;
        }

        // Create head of the list
        Node head;
        
        // Put a new node at the front of the list
    public void push(String new_data)
        {
            // Add data to new_node
            Node new_node = new Node(new_data);
            
            // The new_node.next becomes the new head
            new_node.next = head;
            
            // The head points to the new node 
            head = new_node;    
        }
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            
        // Create the linked list named "rainbow"
        LinkedList<String> rainbow = new LinkedList<String>();
            
        // Add the colors into the linked list
        rainbow.push("Red");
        rainbow.push("Orange");
        rainbow.push("Yellow");
        rainbow.push("Green");
        rainbow.push("Blue");
        rainbow.push("Indigo");
        rainbow.push("Violet");
            
        // Print list
        System.out.println("There are " + rainbow.getLength() + " nodes in total.");
        }
    
    //Call the getCount() function
    public int getLength() {
        return getCount(this.head);
    }
    
    // Count nodes in the linked list
    private int getCount(Node currentPointer)
    {
        // End of the list
        if (currentPointer == null)
            return 0;
        
        // count this node and the rest on the list
        return 1 + getCount(currentPointer.next);
    }
    
    
    }
}
}
```

And also:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

            

public class Rainbow { 

            

            // Create the nodes for the linked list Rainbow

            class Node {

                        int info;

                        Node next;

                        Node(int k)

                        {

                                    info = k;

                                    next = null;

                        }

 

            class ManageNodes {

                        // Create head of the list

                        Node head;

                        

                        // Put a new node at the front of the list

                        public void push(int new_info)

                        {

                                    // Create node pointer and data

                                    Node new_node = new Node(new_info);

                                    

                                    // The new_node.next becomes the new head

                                    new_node.next = head;

                                    

                                    // The head points to the new node

                                    head = new_node;      

                        }

                        

            

            // Count nodes in the linked list

            public int getCountRainbow(Node node)

            {

                        // End of the list

                        if (node ==null)

                                    return 0;

                        

                        // count this node and the rest on the list

                        return 1 + getCountRainbow(node.next);

            }

            

            public int getCount() {return getCountRainbow(head);}

            

            public static void main(String[] args) {

            

                        // Create the linked list named "rainbow"

                        LinkedList rainbow = new LinkedList();

                        

                        // Add the colors into the linked list

                        rainbow.push("Red");

                        rainbow.push("Orange");

                        rainbow.push("Yellow");

                        rainbow.push("Green");

                        rainbow.push("Blue");

                        rainbow.push("Indigo");

                        rainbow.push("Violet");

                        

                        System.out.println("Count of nodes is " + rainbow.getCount());

                        }

            }

}

}
```

I tried reordering the different parts of the code, changing variable types, and moving the main. I continue to get errors.

Comment: Why does your code and with **2** closing braces with no indentation? Find the reason for that, and you'll find the reason why javac can't find your main.

Comment: There is no such thing as a recursive linked list.

Comment: I added extra brackets because the code wouldn't compile without the rainbow class being open, which I thought was weird. Based on the comment below, I'm going to try and separate the two methods, and this way it won't be so muddled anymore hopefully. 

I guess a better labeling of this would be a recursive approach to counting a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

Please save yourself a good deal of trouble and follow standard formatting guidelines and use an autoformatter. Brackets should open and close in a predictable manner and indentation should strictly follow the brackets.

`main` needs to be top-level, and you probably want your classes unnested in general:

```java
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Rainbow {
    // Create the nodes for the linked list Rainbow

    class Node {
        int info;
        Node next;
        Node(int k) {
            info = k;
            next = null;
        }
    }

    class ManageNodes {
        // Create head of the list
        Node head;

        // Put a new node at the front of the list
        public void push(int new_info) {
            // Create node pointer and data
            Node new_node = new Node(new_info);

            // The new_node.next becomes the new head
            new_node.next = head;

            // The head points to the new node
            head = new_node;
        }

        // Count nodes in the linked list
        public int getCountRainbow(Node node) {
            // End of the list
            if (node == null)
                return 0;

            // count this node and the rest on the list
            return 1 + getCountRainbow(node.next);
        }

        public int getCount() { return getCountRainbow(head); }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create the linked list named "rainbow"
        LinkedList rainbow = new LinkedList();

        // Add the colors into the linked list
        rainbow.push("Red");
        rainbow.push("Orange");
        rainbow.push("Yellow");
        rainbow.push("Green");
        rainbow.push("Blue");
        rainbow.push("Indigo");
        rainbow.push("Violet");
        // System.out.println("Count of nodes is " + rainbow.getCount());
    }
}
```

And:

```java
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Rainbow {

    // Create the nodes for the linked list Rainbow
    class Node {
        String data;
        Node next;
        Node(String k) {
            data = k;
            next = null;
        }

        // Create head of the list
        Node head;

        // Put a new node at the front of the list
        public void push(String new_data) {
            // Add data to new_node
            Node new_node = new Node(new_data);

            // The new_node.next becomes the new head
            new_node.next = head;

            // The head points to the new node
            head = new_node;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create the linked list named "rainbow"
        LinkedList<String> rainbow = new LinkedList<String>();

        // Add the colors into the linked list
        rainbow.push("Red");
        rainbow.push("Orange");
        rainbow.push("Yellow");
        rainbow.push("Green");
        rainbow.push("Blue");
        rainbow.push("Indigo");
        rainbow.push("Violet");

        // Print list
        // System.out.println("There are " + rainbow.getLength() +
        //                    " nodes in total.");
    }

    // Call the getCount() function
    // public int getLength() { return getCount(this.head); }

    // Count nodes in the linked list
    private int getCount(Node currentPointer) {
        // End of the list
        if (currentPointer == null)
            return 0;

        // count this node and the rest on the list
        return 1 + getCount(currentPointer.next);
    }
}
```

Both files need to be called Rainbow.java to compile, so I assume they're variants of the same thing.

There are other problems in your code, but this should at least get you moving forward. Any commented-out lines were preventing compilation and need to be fixed.

Taking a further step back, it's unusual use the builtin LinkedList as well as your own linked Node classes. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if this is a data structure exercise, you'd usually implement your own linked list without Java collections. On the other hand, if you're not implementing your own linked list class, skip writing Node and NodeManager classes completely and use the collections API. Calling `rainbow.getCount()` suggests that you are confusing your custom linked list with the builtin Java linked list. Choose one or the other.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, thank you. They are variants of the same thing, I was trying to change it around to see if I could get it to work. I didn't realize I was using two different methods. I'll do my best to separate the two methods and focus on one.
As for the brackets, if I didn't open it to the public rainbow class, it wouldn't let another operation work, which I thought was weird. But worst case, I will reset my code.